# How to use an excel cell as input and write the code answer as an output again in the excel file?

Tags: php, excel

I have a code which gets an input then put it in a formula and at last gives an output. I want the my input value (`$length`) to be set from cell `A2` of `Sheet1` in the `results.xlsx` workbook which is located in the `C:\Users\John\Desktop` directory. It then puts the output value (`$weight`) in cell `B2` in `Sheet1`. Can anybody complete my code?

I really dont need to read an array of inputs, just to read cell `A2` and put the results in cell `B2`. Thank you. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$length=2;
$weight=$length*pi()/tan(0.03);

echo $weight;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste in cell B2: =$A$2*PI()/TAN(0.03)